# PHP MultiDimension Array - How To Group Correctly

Tags: php, mysql, multidimensional-array

How do I properly group an array: (end result)

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Player] => CaLvErT
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [SnapTime] => 1330028992
                    [PlayCount] => 9
                )
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [Player] => CaLvErT
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [SnapTime] => 1330202828
                    [PlayCount] => 8
                )
        )
)
```

My mySQL/PHP goes with what I tried:

```
        $iTestGrid = array();
        $ChartSQL = "SELECT player,snap,count(*) AS pCnt";
        $ChartSQL .= " FROM sc".$DBSvr;
        $ChartSQL .= " WHERE hex(alliance) IN (hex('Twitch'))";
        $ChartSQL .= " GROUP BY player,snap";
        $ChartSQL .= " ORDER BY player ASC,snap ASC";
        $FinalResult = $db-> query($ChartSQL);
        while ($FinalRow = $db-> fetch_assoc($FinalResult)){
           $iTestGrid[] = array(
            'Player' => $FinalRow['player'],
            array(
                'SnapTime' => (int)$FinalRow['snap'],
                'PlayCount' => (int)$FinalRow['pCnt']
            )
           );
        }
```

Basically wanted to know how to group a player, that has the same name.

Thanks in advance for your help!  (Forgive me for I'm not keen on understanding fully how arrays work, been thru bookstore all day/night and still get parts of it, not a whole lot)

Comment: How is you db organized? Any `SELECT` queries you may add to question?

Comment: not sure if it makes all the differences but I added the SQL Parm to it.  Hope that helps!

Comment: Just tought that sql server could propably sort data for you so that you dont need to do so much looping over array with php.

Comment: Yeah, it works if I do an Echo and loop it with .=, but that won't work with JQuery's chart that I'm trying to work with, so was advised that array would work like charm.  Honestly was TRYING to avoid array for a long time, but guess sometimes we gotta learn it one way or the other haha..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want  something like that if I understand correctly.
You can use the player name as key for grouping, and push playcount/timestamp values into the same array.

```
<?php 
    $iTestGrid = array();
    $ChartSQL = "SELECT player,snap,count(*) AS pCnt";
    $ChartSQL .= " FROM sc".$DBSvr;
    $ChartSQL .= " WHERE hex(alliance) IN (hex('Twitch'))";
    $ChartSQL .= " GROUP BY player,snap";
    $ChartSQL .= " ORDER BY player ASC,snap ASC";
    $FinalResult = $db-> query($ChartSQL);

    while ($FinalRow = $db-> fetch_assoc($FinalResult)){

        if(!isset($iTestGrid[$FinalRow['player']]))
            $iTestGrid[$FinalRow['player']] = array();

        $iTestGrid[$FinalRow['player']][] = 
        array(
            'SnapTime' => (int)$FinalRow['snap'],
            'PlayCount' => (int)$FinalRow['pCnt']
        );
    }

    var_dump($iTestGrid);
```

Comment: Yes, that is correct.  Let me try your method and see how it works out for me.

Comment: Now I see what is been done.. Yup it works well :)

Basically telling mySQL if this is not already "key'd" then add it, then "push" (as you say), adding "sub-array" to the existing key and repeat until the main key doesn't match, then go make a new array, correct? (hope the concept is correct)

Comment: Tufan, hope you're still around to assist me once more, with what you gave me above, how do I add "Player" in front of $FinalRow['player']?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use `player name`s as array keys and insert other data inside that array:

```
$sorted = array();
foreach ( $result as $value ) {
    $sorted[ $value['Player'] ] = $value[ 0 ];
}
var_dump( $sorted );
```

Comment: with that you only need to setup new array at first while loop, i'm writing with phone so it's more pseudocode. Replace foreach with while and get $value straight from there.